# Why am I unable to achieve 2560x1080 resolution using a Radeon HD 8370D graphics chipset?

Tags: windows-10, hdmi, resolution, amd-radeon, amd-graphics-card

I have a client who has recently bought an AOC Q34E2A ultrawide monitor, with a native resolution of 2560x1080. It comes equipped with 2 HDMI ports and a DisplayPort. I am using one of the HDMI ports.

**Windows insists that the maximum (and recommended) resolution it can output to that monitor is 1920x1080.**

Her graphics card, as reported in Device Manager, is an AMD Radeon HD 8370D. I suspect this may be built into her CPU, although at this point in time I am not certain.

Maybe the graphics card is just too old and crappy. I have tried googling to determine if this graphics chipset is able to reach the required resolution, and haven't managed to find any definitive answers. According to [techpowerup.com](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/radeon-hd-8370d-igp.c2000), the chipset is capable of both 1920x1080 and 2560x1440, so I would assume that 2560x1080 should be possible.

My google searches mostly came up with other people's questions of the form "why won't Windows 10 let me use ultrawide monitors anymore?" and did not offer any conclusive answers or solutions.

So...what am I doing wrong? Does she need a new graphics card? If so, how can I tell if a specific card will do the job?

​Is it Windows 10's fault? If so, is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: How is the monitor connected? HDMI or display port?

Comment: HDMI. Sorry, I should have said. Will edit.

Comment: Why are you not using the DisplayPort? Are you using the latest display driver?

Comment: Because the computer doesn't have a DisplayPort. Also the monitor didn't ship with a DP cable. I checked Windows Update for a newer driver, and it didn't find one. Admittedly I didn't check the manufacturer's website, but in any case there have been no new drivers for that chipset since 2016.

Comment: Monitors also have drivers. It's just a text file. See Windows *Monitor.inf* for all common monitors. (`C:\Windows\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\monitor.inf_amd64_8a98af5011ee4dc6\monitor.inf`). See https://eu.aoc.com/en/products/monitors/q34e2a/downloads

Comment: Sadly, I already installed the monitor driver. It didn't help.

Comment: Have you have gone into the monitor's setup and chosen the aspect ratio you want using the buttons on the monitor. I read the manual.

Comment: Although I didn't see your chiplist as a supported one unless it goes by a family name.

Comment: I did indeed check the aspect ratio settings in the menu. And installed the configuration software that came on the disc also.

Answer (score 0):

Download the drivers over at https://eu.aoc.com/api/frontberg/downloadable/3f37e448-c66f-4b4e-8321-eeea87e5812b/Q34E2A.zip

I found them at https://eu.aoc.com/nl/products/monitors/q34e2a/downloads

Comment: The monitor came with the drivers on a CD. They didn't help, sadly.

Comment: @InfinityComputers with the same driver version?

Comment: some guy with a similar monitor reports that he changed from HDMI (max 1920x1080) to DVI and got the max resolution. https://www.sevenforums.com/graphic-cards/419305-monitor-not-full-resolution-2.html?s=ddc88b437b429086d338c667bf65ca1d Get a decent GPU with a displayport

Comment: I'm not sure. I would have to check. I guess it's possible that the disc has been kicking around for months in a warehouse.

Comment: The problem with "a decent GPU" is that I'm not sure how to determine before purchase if any given graphics card would be able to output the correct resolution. I'm pretty sure they don't come with an exhaustive list of supported resolutions.

Comment: Why would changing from HDMI to DP solve the problem? Is there some reason HDMI would be "crippled" in this way? Why would anyone sell a monitor with an HDMI port if it couldn't be used properly via HDMI?

Comment: https://community.amd.com/t5/graphics/i-can-t-get-2560x1440-resolution-even-though-the-monitor-and/td-p/363753

Comment: So...am I understanding this correctly? The monitor *can* do full resolution via HDMI, but the computer cannot? Because (presumably) it's an FM2 CPU rather than an FM2+?